# MySQL select highest amount

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a SELECT query that will show the lowest invoice amount of each supplier in the table below. Tried a few solutions but can't get my head around it! Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the lowest invoice_price by supplier_name You can use aggregation function MIN with group by

```
select supplier_name, min(invoce_price)
from my_table 
group by supplier_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min aggregation function with group by clause

```
select supplier_name, min(invoice_price) from table_name group by supplier_name
```

Similarly to get the highest amount, use max aggregation function

```
select supplier_name, max(invoice_price) from table_name group by supplier_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want columns like the invoice number/date, you will need to write 2 queries, I usually prefer to write a tmp table for this sort of task.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_min_value; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_min_value AS 
SELECT [key columns eg. supplier], min(invoice_price) as min_invoice_value
FROM supplier_invocies
GROUP BY [key columns eg. supplier];

SELECT is.*
FROM supplier_invoices si
INNER JOIN tmp_min_value tmv
  ON si.supplier_name = tmv.supplier_name
  AND si.invoice_price = tmv.min_invoice_value;
```

You may get multiple invoices per supplier, if there are multiple invoices with the same invoice price. You can get rid of this by using another join if you need a specific (eg. the last relevant invoice) or just by grouping the relevant columns and using MIN() on the invoice_price again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME, MIN(INVOICE_PRICE)
FROM SUPPLIER_INVOICES 
GROUP BY SUPPLIER_NAME;
```